# Docker: Connect docker container straight to hosts LAN

Tags: networking, lan, docker

I have 2 docker containers, 1 running pihole and another running Nextcloud. Right now, they are both using the default bridge, pihole running on the hosts port 80 and Nextcloud on the hosts port 8080. Ideally, I want the docker container to have its own IP on the LAN, so instead of running on the hosts IP it runs in the LAN, where it can be accessed by other machines on the network. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself. I had to create a macvlan for this to work. In portainer (what I use for docker management), I create a macvlan configuration with the same gateway and subnet of my LAN, and then set the IP address range of 192.168.1.100/32 (so it gets the IP 192.168.1.100). Then, I made the actual macvlan from the config called macvlan100, and attached it to the container using the command `docker network connect macvlan100 charming_hoover`, which gave the container the IP of 192.168.1.100.